# I want to fill the gridview rows with the data selected in popup window

Tags: c#, asp.net

i want to fill the grid view rows with the data selected in popup window

I attached a sample image link

[https://photos.google.com/search/*tra*/photo/AF1QipNHlfe6sBiAsY9_czvTF8JJn8kIzBOV6RbjP2dw](https://photos.google.com/search/_tra_/photo/AF1QipNHlfe6sBiAsY9_czvTF8JJn8kIzBOV6RbjP2dw)

Comment: One option you may use is `query string`

Comment: Insert your popup window data to database and, call database to your gridview